# How to keep gmail threads from coming back

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have this function, which I run hourly.  It checks the inbox for messages that are to a mailing list.  It then reformats them a bit, saves attachments, and forwards them along to another email address, and then ostensibly throws away the processed messages.  Works pretty well, except....

I have recently encountered a thread that just won't die.  It's got well over 50 replies, and when new replies come in with the same subject line all of the old messages in the thread that have already been processed, get processed again.  So my sent box grows exponentially, as does the recipient email inbox.  I'm not sure if I'm simply not deleting the sent messages effectively, or if there is some other way I should be identifying already processed messages within a thread so they don't get processed again when more messages are added to the thread.  I can't tell if this is an app script problem or a gmail problem.

Here's my code:

```
function processPMFMail(){
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var message = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
  for(var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < message[i].length; j++) {
      var from = message[i][j].getFrom();
      var to = message[i][j].getTo();
      var cc = message[i][j].getCc();
      var bcc = message[i][j].getBcc();
      var fields = {to, cc, bcc};
                    //Logger.log(to);

                    if (
                    [to,cc,bcc].some(field =>
                    ["EMAIL-1","EMAIL-2"].some(email => field.includes(email))
                    )
                    ) {
                    var subject = cleanSubject(message[i][j]);
                    if (subject == "DoNotPost") {
                    Logger.log("Email not for posting - " + cleanSubject(message[i][j]));
                    message[i][j].moveToTrash();
                   } else{
                    var from = parseEmailName(message[i][j]);
                    var body = message[i][j].getPlainBody();
                    var hBody = message[i][j].getBody();
                    var attachment = saveAttachments(message[i][j]);
                    var opening = "<br>From: " + from + "<br> Sent: "+ Utilities.formatDate(message[i][j].getDate(), "US/Eastern", "M/d/yy @ h:mm aaa") + "<br><br>" + attachment;
                    if (hBody.indexOf("</body>")>-1) {
                    hBody = removeForwards (hBody);
                    hBody = hBody.replace("</body>",opening + "</body>").trim();
                   } else{
                    hBody = hBody + opening;
                   }
                    Logger.log(subject + opening);
                    //send the message
                    GmailApp.sendEmail("EMAIL-3", subject , opening + body , 
                    {htmlBody: hBody, 
                    name: from
                   })  
    }  // end of processed messages
    //move the message to the trash
    message[i][j].moveToTrash();
  } 
  else {Logger.log("No Messages to forward")}
}
}

}
```

Any pointers gratefully appreciated.

-DH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So If I understood correctly you are getting all the message from a thread over and over.

But in the end this is expected as you are getting first the [`GmailThread`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) and then checking every [`GmailMessage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#isintrash) in the thread. Even if you have already checked it up and deleted it is part of the Thread and is normal that you get it back when using [`getMessagesForThreads()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagesforthreadsthreads).

I would recommend using [`isInTrash()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#isintrash) in every message (inside the for nested loop), to check if you have already moved this message to the trash.

Something like this:

```
function processPMFMail() {
    var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
    var message = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < message[i].length; j++) {
            if (!message[i][j].isInTrash()) {
                var from = message[i][j].getFrom();
                var to = message[i][j].getTo();
                var cc = message[i][j].getCc();
                var bcc = message[i][j].getBcc();
                var from = message[i][j].getFrom();
                var fields = { to, cc, bcc };
                //Logger.log(to);

                if (
                    [to, cc, bcc].some(field =>
                        ["EMAIL-1", "EMAIL-2"].some(email => field.includes(email))
                    )
                ) {
                    var subject = cleanSubject(message[i][j]);
                    if (subject == "DoNotPost") {
                        Logger.log("Email not for posting - " + cleanSubject(message[i][j]));
                        message[i][j].moveToTrash();
                    } else {
                        var from = parseEmailName(message[i][j]);
                        var body = message[i][j].getPlainBody();
                        var hBody = message[i][j].getBody();
                        var attachment = saveAttachments(message[i][j]);
                        var opening = "<br>From: " + from + "<br> Sent: " + Utilities.formatDate(message[i][j].getDate(), "US/Eastern", "M/d/yy @ h:mm aaa") + "<br><br>" + attachment;
                        if (hBody.indexOf("</body>") > -1) {
                            hBody = removeForwards(hBody);
                            hBody = hBody.replace("</body>", opening + "</body>").trim();
                        } else {
                            hBody = hBody + opening;
                        }
                        Logger.log(subject + opening);
                        //send the message
                        GmailApp.sendEmail("EMAIL-3", subject, opening + body,
                            {
                                htmlBody: hBody,
                                name: from
                            })
                    }  // end of processed messages
                    //move the message to the trash
                    message[i][j].moveToTrash();
                }
                else { Logger.log("No Messages to forward") }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool.  I'll give that a try. Does the ! in front of  `message[i][j].isInTrash()` mean "not"  as in "if not in trash?"

Comment: Exactly. You can take a look at this [page for boolean comparison in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Such a simple answer.  Sometimes, you just can't see it staring you in the face.  Thanks.